# Error when using Len()

Tags: vb.net, string-length

I have the following block of code:

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal adate AS String) AS String
    Dim len AS Integer = Len(adate) /*problem line*/
    Dim strSubstr AS String = Mid(adate, 0, len-2)
    Dim compStr AS String = strSubstr + "00"

    return compStr
End Function
```

I'm getting an error:

> Expression is not an array or method, and cannot have an argument list

I'm new to VB but I feel like I'm doing this correctly, what am I missing here?

EDIT:

This is what finally worked for me:

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal adate AS String) AS String
    Dim mylen AS Integer = adate.Length
    Dim strSubstr AS String = adate.Substring(0, mylen-2)
    Dim compStr AS String = strSubstr & "00"

    return compStr
End Function
```

Comment: Strongly suggest you get familiar with VB.NET syntax and string operations, rather than legacy VB syntax.   Just my 2 cents though.

Comment: Len() is a legacy function and should only ever be used in code that was converted from old projects.  Use adata.Length instead.

Comment: Thank you Hans that fixed it!

Comment: Len => string.Length, Mid => string.Substring and finally use & to concatenate not +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was giving you an error because you were using a vb keyword (len) as a variable.

Try this:

```
 Public Function GetDate(ByVal adate As String) As String
        Dim myLen As Integer = Len(adate)
        Dim strSubstr As String = Mid(adate, 0, myLen - 2)
        Dim compStr As String = strSubstr + "00"

        Return compStr
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what finally worked for me:

```
Public Function GetDate(ByVal adate AS String) AS String
    Dim mylen AS Integer = adate.Length
    Dim strSubstr AS String = adate.Substring(0, mylen-2)
    Dim compStr AS String = strSubstr & "00"

    return compStr
End Function
```

Comment: I would be curious to see the code that calls this method. Are you trimming away the seconds from a DateTime variable?

Comment: code that calls this is: Code.GetDate(Parameters!period.Value). I'm stripping the end values from a "period" that's coming from our database. For instance January would be '201601' so I strip the '01', add '00' and return '201600' for the value of a query parameter looking for the start of the year

Comment: Well not what I thought, but if you have always the full year then you could simply write _return adata.Substring(0,4) & "00"_